# Non-Linear Regression involving the maximum function

Tags: regression, regression-analysis

How do you calculate the regression of this model?

I know Minitab and MATLAB, so if you guide me with these software I would totally appreciate it.

$$Y=c+\max(X^{-n}, 0.34)
$$

Here c and n are positive parameters.

Transformation increases the residuals, I want to solve it as it is.

Comment: Please don't use _help_ in title, it's redundant. Have you looked up  "curve-fitting in Matlab"? What makes this particular instance off curve fitting hard?

Comment: In the exponent, is $n$ integer ?